# WebRTC - Blazor - Remote stream not showing

Tags: javascript, blazor, webrtc

I'm trying to make a simple webcam sharing app using WebRTC and Blazor. I'm getting the 'ontrack' event firing on the client with a track, but it's not showing in the browser.

I also get the following error when I try only launch one browser (and try to send/receive in the same window), not sure if that's possible? Obviously would be useless in the real-world, but was doing it for testing.

Error 'Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable'

Any help would be appreciated?

Blazor Code

```
@using Google.Cloud.Firestore;
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

<h3>ScreenShare</h3>

<div id="buttons">
<button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised" id="cameraBtn" @onclick="openUserMedia">
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">perm_camera_mic</i>
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Open camera & microphone</span>
</button>
<button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised" id="createBtn" @onclick="createRoom">
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">group_add</i>
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Create room</span>
</button>
<button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised" id="joinBtn" @onclick="joinRoom">
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">group</i>
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Join room</span>
</button>
<button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised" id="hangupBtn" @onclick="hangUp">
    <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">close</i>
    <span class="mdc-button__label">Hangup</span>
</button>
<input type="text" id="room-id" @bind="@roomID">
</div>
<div id="videos">
    <video id="localVideo" muted autoplay playsinline></video>
    <video id="remoteVideo" muted autoplay playsinline></video>
</div>

@code {
private static Func<object, Task> OnIceCandidateAction;
private static Func<object, Task> OnIceCandidateAnswerAction;

private FirestoreDb _db;
private DocumentReference _callDoc;

private string roomID { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();

    OnIceCandidateAction = OnIceCandidiate;
    OnIceCandidateAnswerAction = OnIceCandidateAnswer_Local;

    InitialiseFirebase();
    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("init");
}

private void InitialiseFirebase()
{
    string filepath = @"<Path_to_firebase_config>";
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", filepath);
    string projectID = "fir-rtc-a3a58";

    this._db = FirestoreDb.Create(projectID);
}

private async void openUserMedia()
{
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("openUserMedia");
}

private async void createRoom()
{
    this._callDoc = this._db.Collection("calls").Document();
    this.roomID = this._callDoc.Id;

    CollectionReference answerCandidates = this._callDoc.Collection("answerCandidates");

    var offer = await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("createRoom"); //Update to return offer

    Dictionary<string, string> offerValues = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(offer.ToString());
    await this._callDoc.SetAsync(offerValues);

    this._callDoc.Listen(async snapshot =>
    {
        string type = snapshot.GetValue<string>("type");
        if (type != "answer")
            return;

        Dictionary<string, object> data = snapshot.ToDictionary();
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setRemote", data);
    });

    answerCandidates.Listen(snapshot =>
    {
        if (snapshot is QuerySnapshot)
        {
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot as QuerySnapshot;
            foreach (DocumentChange change in querySnapshot.Changes)
            {
                if (change.ChangeType == DocumentChange.Type.Added)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> data = change.Document.ToDictionary();

                    object candidate;
                    data.TryGetValue("candidate", out candidate);

                    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("addICECandidate", candidate);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private async void joinRoom()
{
    this._callDoc = this._db.Collection("calls").Document(roomID);
    CollectionReference offerCandidates = this._callDoc.Collection("offerCandidates");

    DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await this._callDoc.GetSnapshotAsync();
    Dictionary<string, object> data = docSnapshot.ToDictionary();
    var answer = await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("joinRoom", data);

    Dictionary<string, string> answerValues = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(answer.ToString());
    await this._callDoc.SetAsync(answerValues);

    offerCandidates.Listen(snapshot =>
    {
        if (snapshot is QuerySnapshot)
        {
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot as QuerySnapshot;
            foreach (DocumentChange change in querySnapshot.Changes)
            {
                if (change.ChangeType == DocumentChange.Type.Added)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> data = change.Document.ToDictionary();

                    object candidate;
                    data.TryGetValue("candidate", out candidate);

                    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("addICECandidate", candidate);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void hangUp()
{
    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("hangUp");
}

#region ICE Candidates - Offer

[JSInvokable]
public static async Task OnIceCandidate(object e)
{
    await OnIceCandidateAction?.Invoke(e);
}

private async Task OnIceCandidiate(object e)
{
    CollectionReference offerCandidates = this._callDoc.Collection("offerCandidates");

    Dictionary<string, string> candidateValues = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(e.ToString());
    await offerCandidates.AddAsync(candidateValues);
}

#endregion

#region ICE Candidates - Answer

[JSInvokable]
public static async Task OnIceCandidateAnswer(object e)
{
    await OnIceCandidateAnswerAction?.Invoke(e);
}

private async Task OnIceCandidateAnswer_Local(object e)
{
    CollectionReference answerCandidates = this._callDoc.Collection("answerCandidates");

    Dictionary<string, string> candidateValues = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(e.ToString());
    await answerCandidates.AddAsync(candidateValues);
}

#endregion
}
```

Javascript

```
mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-button'));

const configuration = {
    iceServers: [
        {
            urls: [
                'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
                'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
            ],
        },
    ],
    iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
};

let peerConnection = null;
let localStream = null;
let remoteStream = null;

let roomDialog = null;
let roomId = null;

function init() {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    remoteStream = new MediaStream();

    peerConnection.ontrack = event => {
        event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
            remoteStream.addTrack(track);
        });
    };

    document.querySelector('#remoteVideo').srcObject = remoteStream;
}

async function openUserMedia(e) {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
        { video: true, audio: true });
    document.querySelector('#localVideo').srcObject = stream;
    localStream = stream;
}

async function createRoom() {
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });

    peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', event => {
        if (event.candidate) {
            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('ScreenShareClient', 'OnIceCandidate', event.candidate.toJSON());
        }
    });

    const offerDescription = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offerDescription);

    const offer = {
        sdp: offerDescription.sdp,
        type: offerDescription.type,
    };

    return offer;
}

async function joinRoom(offer) {
    peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', event => {
        if (event.candidate) {
            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('ScreenShareClient', 'OnIceCandidateAnswer', event.candidate.toJSON());
        }
    });

    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));

    const answerDescription = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answerDescription);

    const answer = {
        type: answerDescription.type,
        sdp: answerDescription.sdp
    };

    return answer;
}

function setRemote(answer) {
    const answerDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(answer);
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answerDescription);
}

function addICECandidate(candidate) {
    peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
}

async function hangUp(e) {
    const tracks = document.querySelector('#localVideo').srcObject.getTracks();
    tracks.forEach(track => {
        track.stop();
    });

    if (remoteStream) {
        remoteStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }

    if (peerConnection) {
        peerConnection.close();
    }
}
```